# shared pointer return and object lifetime

Tags: c++

I have classes A and B

```
class A{};

class B {
   private:
      shared_ptr<A> spa;
   public:
      B() {
         //init spa
      }
   //...
};
```

Should I do:

```
shared_ptr<B> func() {
   //....
   return shared_ptr<B>(new B);
}
```

or is best to do:

```
B* func(){return new B;}
shared_ptr<B> caller=shared_ptr<B>(func());
```

---

Also, makes more sense to return a reference to a shared_ptr like:

```
shared_ptr<B>& func() {
   //....
   return shared_ptr<B>(new B);
}
```

or a pointer to a shared_ptr

```
shared_ptr<B>* func() {
   //....
   return &shared_ptr<B>(new B);
}
```

Comment: That last code snippet won't work, you're returning a pointer to a temporary. Besides, having a pointer to a shared pointer seldom makes much sense. And don't return by reference either, that code snippet returns a reference to a temporary value. Instead return *by value*. One of the points with the smart pointers is that you should be able to treat them as *values*, and they have proper operators and constructors to handle that.

Comment: Half of your code isn't even valid. Please put more effort into this question.

Answer (score 0):

The first two options are mostly a question of programming style. I find the first one clearer and easier to read.

The other two examples are plain wrong. The don't work, because you return a reference to a temporary or a pointer to a temporary. Both will break your program.

Answer (score 0):

I would transfer ownership with make_shared:

```
std::shared_ptr<Y> func()
{
    return std::make_shared<B>();
}
```